# Cover an image?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to have a opaque black sheet over my image.

```
<div class="bg-black z-50 absolute" >
  <img class="" src="https://www.apimages.com/Images/Ap_Creative_Stock_Header.jpg" alt="Flying Kites">
</div>
```

I've searched but only found solutions to do it with html/css and using background-image which is something I cannot use in my project.  How do I get a black square (that's fitted to the image, no overlap, or excess) without knowing the image width/height (it will change).

Tried variations of the above, but nothing is showing up (no black on the screen)

Comment: So what can you use in your project? Be specific.

Comment: @user202729 just an image tag. We made it a "background image by using absolute and relative. Adding additional code...

Comment: So "homework assignment"? In that case the first step would be to understand absolute and relative first and see how it can be applied (and perhaps some other related things like z-index, left or top)

Comment: @user202729 nope, done with school. this is a project. we've tried using z-index. it's not doing anything. Not sure how to get the "cover" too have the correct w/h. Even after trying something like w-full

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your markup you can set the `background-color` of your container div to black and reduce the `opacity` of your image.

```css
.bg-black {
  background-color: #000;
}

.bg-black img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-black z-50 absolute">
  <img class="" src="https://www.apimages.com/Images/Ap_Creative_Stock_Header.jpg" alt="Flying Kites">
</div>
```

Alternatively you can absolutely position a div over the top of your image and set its opacity there:

```css
.bg-black {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-black z-50 absolute">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img class="" src="https://www.apimages.com/Images/Ap_Creative_Stock_Header.jpg" alt="Flying Kites">
</div>
```